# EditorFor Field for List object that maps to a different model?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a `fieldset` in my view where users can create a post at the same time I have a list of `Tags` that can be selected at creation time and associated in my many to many relationship in EF with `Post`, this creates a relationship between the `Post` and the `Tag` in `PostTagMap` upon saving the post. However I want to add in an extra field in the view so the user can also "create" a tag (type in a name) aswell as selecting tags however I cant figure out the last issue in my jQuery to make it work.

View:

```
@model MyBlogger.Models.Post
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for Post
  ....
  <div id="tags">
    for (int i = 0; i < tag.Count; i++)
    {
      var id = string.Format("tag{0}", tag[i].Id);
      var isChecked = tag[i].IsAssigned ? "checked" : null;
      <div class="tag">
        <input id="@id" type="checkbox" name="selectedTags" value="@tag[i].Id" @isChecked />
        <label for="@id">@tag[i].Name</label>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
  <button id="addtag" type="button">Add new tag</button>
  <div id="dialog" style="display:none">
  @Html.Action("CreateTag")
}
```

**Post Controller:**

```
// Returns a partial view with a form to create a new Tag
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult CreateTag()
{
  Tag model = new Tag();
  return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTag(Tag model)
{
  // Save the Tag
  db.Tags.Add(model);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Name = model.Name });
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model MyBlogger.Models.Tag
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for Tag
  ....
  <button id="createtag" type="button">Create</button>
}
```

PostController

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult CreateTag()
{
  Tag model = new Tag();
  return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTag(Tag model)
{
  // Save the Tag
  db.Tags.Add(model);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Name = model.Name });
}
```

Script

```
var dialog = $('#dialog');
var tags = $('#tags');
var url = '@Url.Action("CreateTag")';
$('#addtag').click(function() {
  dialog.show();
});
$('#createtag').click(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data) {
      var id = tags.children('.tag').length;
      var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('tag');
      .... stuck here
      div.append($('<label></label>').attr('for', id).text(data.Name));
      tags.append(div);
      form.get(0).reset(); // reset controls to their defaults
      dialog.hide(); // hide the dialog
    }
```

Comment: Best to use a popup form for creating the new tag, then use ajax to post it to a controller which saves it and returns json indicating its new id and the display name and use that to update the DOM with a new checkbox

Comment: Give me an hour or two to finish what I'm working on and I'll give you a simplified example. but you really need to start using view models to represent what you want to edit :)

Comment: Because it the correct approach. You just don't realize yet the problems you could face, particularly if you start adding validation attributes to your properties. Then of course there are issues with over-posting attacks. And mapping view models to data models and vice-versa is easy if you use tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). This alone `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BlogUserEmail, User.Identity.Name)` is an issue. You should not be including that in your view, rather setting its value in the POST method when you save the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional methods in your controller for creating a new `Tag`

PostController

```
// Returns a partial view with a form to create a new Tag
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult CreateTag()
{
  Tag model = new Tag();
  return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTag(Tag model)
{
  // Save the Tag
  db.Tags.Add(model);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Name = model.Name });
}
```

Partial View

```
@model MyBlogger.Models.Tag
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for Tag
  ....
  <button id="createtag" type="button">Create</button>
}
```

Main View

```
@model MyBlogger.Models.Post
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for Post
  ....
  <div id="tags">
    // not sure what you trying to do with you existing code, but
    for (int i = 0; i < tag.Count; i++)
    {
      var id = string.Format("tag{0}", tag[i].Id);
      var isChecked = tag[i].IsAssigned ? "checked" : null;
      <div class="tag">
        <input id="@id" type="checkbox" name="selectedTags" value="@tag[i].Id" @isChecked />
        <label for="@id">@tag[i].Name</label>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
  <button id="addtag" type="button">Add new tag</button>
  ....
}
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
  @Html.Action("CreateTag")
</div> // outside main form tags!
```

Script

```
var dialog = $('#dialog');
var tags = $('#tags');
var url = '@Url.Action("CreateTag")';
$('#addtag').click(function() {
  dialog.show();
});
$('#createtag').click(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data) {
      var id = tags.children('.tag').length;
      var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('tag');
      div.append($('<input/>').val(data.ID).attr({ type: 'checkbox', name: 'selectedTags', id: id }).prop('checked', true));
      div.append($('<label></label>').attr('for', id).text(data.Name));
      tags.append(div);
      form.get(0).reset(); // reset controls to their defaults
      dialog.hide(); // hide the dialog
    }
  });
});
```

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn0c2su9/) for an example of how you might style the dialog and the tag checkboxes and their labels

Side notes:

1. I strongly recommend your start using view models to represent only
   the properties you need to display/edit in the view.
2. Tables are for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76061/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-muecke-editorfor-field-for-list-object-that-maps).